# Accessing an Angular micro frontend from the host app using module federation

Tags: javascript, angular, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I have created a microfrontend(mfe) in Angular using module federation.
Below are the steps that I used to create the mfe:

1. I have run: ng new mfes --standalone false
2. After navigating in the 'mfes' directory, I ran the command: ng generate application product-listing.
3. I navigated in product-listing and ran the command: npm install @angular-architects/module-federation.
4. A file called webpack.config.js was created.
   I modified the content of the file as follows:

```js
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, '../../tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "productListing",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For remotes (please adjust)
        name: "productListing",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
            './ProductListingModule': './projects/product-listing/src/app/app.component.ts',
        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

The folder structure of the 'product-listing' mfe is below:

[image]

In a different folder, I have created a host app which I called main-app, using the command: new new main-app --standalone false. I have also added module federation.
Below is the config in the file webpack.config.js

```js
const ModuleFederationPlugin = require("webpack/lib/container/ModuleFederationPlugin");
const mf = require("@angular-architects/module-federation/webpack");
const path = require("path");
const share = mf.share;

const sharedMappings = new mf.SharedMappings();
sharedMappings.register(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
  [/* mapped paths to share */]);

module.exports = {
  output: {
    uniqueName: "mainApp",
    publicPath: "auto"
  },
  optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      ...sharedMappings.getAliases(),
    }
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        library: { type: "module" },

        // For hosts (please adjust)
        remotes: {
          "productListing": "productListing@http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",

        },

        shared: share({
          "@angular/core": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/common/http": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },
          "@angular/router": { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' },

          ...sharedMappings.getDescriptors()
        })

    }),
    sharedMappings.getPlugin()
  ],
};
```

Below is the folder structure:

[image]

I have also added the route for this mfe in the app.module.ts. Please find the file below:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import { loadRemoteModule } from '@angular-architects/module-federation';


const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'product-listing', loadChildren: () => loadRemoteModule(
      {
        type: "module",
        remoteEntry:"http://localhost:3000/remoteEntry.js",
        exposedModule: './ProductListingModule'
      }).then(m => m.ProductListingModule) },
  
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am serving the mfe 'product-listing' and can be accessed via localhost:3000
I am running the main-app (host app) and it can be accessed via localhost:4000.
However, when I am accessing localhost:4000/product-listing, I am getting the following error:`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ɵmod')` in the console. The URL is also changed back to localhost:4000.